# png file will be broken by release build of flutter

Tags: android, flutter

i made a flutter application using [flutter local notification package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) for Andriod.

According to the sample of the pakcage, i put a png file "app_icon.png" into *app-root*/android/app/src/main/res/drawable.

its ok by debug build, application will show that icon in Android's notification.
but on release build, application show a blank image.

i tried to "unzip" 2 apk files, release-built and debug-one and check that app_icon file.
i found a corrupt png file in releae apk. (debug apk's file is collect.)

why debug build will broke png file ??

procedure that i build:

- flutter build appbundle
- flutter build apk

capture broken/collect png files:

- [broken icon on Android Notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7f7s.png)
- [collect png in debug build apk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Y5ly.png)
- [corrupt when release build apk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9DuE.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are seeing the icon in debug and it's missing in release, open the `build/app/outputs/apk/app-release.apk` in Androiod Studio and see if it's in there and has the correct size & colors.

If it's is missing or 'blank' you need to add it to res/raw/keep.xml (example below, update to your drawable)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- since we only reference this in flutter code, it would get stripped 
 out otherwise -->
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   tools:keep="@drawable/ic_notification*" />
```

More info here - https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#keep-resources

Answer (score 0):

The pngs do not work with the notification icons as Android dyes all the space occupied by the image in the notification icon as you can see from the photos you posted.

**Solution:** Use an XML drawable.